# Evernote and Producteev GUI Toolkit

Tags: windows, user-interface

I was looking at Evernote and Producteev for Windows and noticed they used similar GUI toolkits. What tookit(s) are they using? Here's some links., [Producteev](http://www.producteev.com/appstore.php). (Check the Windows Screenshots) and [Evernote](http://i1-win.softpedia-static.com/screenshots/EverNote_3.png).

Answer (score 3):

I am the programmer for the Windows desktop application for Producteev. We didn't use any toolkits for the GUI. All of the UI code was written from scratch based on designs from our in-house artist. We drew a little bit of influence from Evernote (particularly in the toolbar area) to give a familiar look to the application, so that's why there's some similarities.

The application itself is written in C#, and I use GDI+ to make all the drawing calls. There are about a dozen custom-written controls, including buttons (some of which bring down menus), glowing text boxes, list boxes (for tasks). There's also another collection of them to replace for all of the default Windows controls in order to force anti-aliased text rasterizing.

Comment: The visual components apart from the task list took around 1 month to develop. The task list is a bit harder to tell since it is so tightly integrated into the Model and controllers, but I would venture to guess probably around 2 weeks by itself.

Comment: Interesting, I'm looking at writing my own tookit and that was very good information thank you.